# Override android headset hook long press

Tags: android

I need to override the android heaset hook button, the long press causes the music player starts auntomatically and I need  to avoid this.

Is it possible in Android?

I try:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it not works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to just create your own gesture recognition to account for a long press. You can start a timer on KeyDown and then check that timer on KeyUp to see if the key up was at or lower than your long press time. Or you can use the getEventTime methods to do the same function. If your question was more specific on how to intercept the headset buttons I would recommend this article, [Allowing applications to play nice(r) with each other: Handling remote control buttons](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html).

If you need some other kind of help or some code samples let me know